# Why installing Blazor on mobile gives an error Couldn't install web app

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a program with Blazor WebAssembly App (vs 2022) that I wrote with .Net Core 6, the program does not install on the mobile and gives the error 'Couldn't install web app'.

Even if I created a raw project, it won't install.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is a PWA application. by installation, I mean that in pwa programs, it is possible to install it like an apk file, not to create its shortcut . for example, in the Samsung browser. publish by method:Folder (publish your application to a local folder or file server) and server vps/delicate server . windos server iis